# Sorting In AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

```
self.records: [
  {
    "Reg_code": 10001025,
    "Name": "Chandan Kumar Penta",
    "staticColumn": {
      "Check": "Check1",
      "HHHHH": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "Reg_code": 10001290,
    "Name": "test_B2 ",
    "staticColumn": {
      "Check": "Check2",
      "HHHHH": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "Reg_code": 10001028,
    "Name": "Ronny Lewis",
    "staticColumn": {
      "Check": "Check3",
      "HHHHH": ""
    }
  }
]
```

This is my JSON object. I want to sort on the basis on **Check** in AngularJS. Please help.

Comment: you mean you need to filter the record  by check?

Comment: @Yogiraj on the basis of  check means the key check in each object present in stationColumn object??

Comment: Please check here http://plnkr.co/edit/S5PwRWQFmQekoPPFFpGk?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do,

```
<div class="adaptions" ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy:'staticColumn.Check' ">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.records  = [
  {
    "Reg_code": 10001025,
    "Name": "Chandan Kumar Penta",
    "staticColumn": {
      "Check": "Check4",
      "HHHHH": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "Reg_code": 10001290,
    "Name": "test_B2 ",
    "staticColumn": {
      "Check": "Check2",
      "HHHHH": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "Reg_code": 10001028,
    "Name": "Ronny Lewis",
    "staticColumn": {
      "Check": "Check3",
      "HHHHH": ""
    }
  }
];
   
  
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="dobController">
 <div class="adaptions" ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy:'staticColumn.Check' ">
     <ul>
       <li >{{ record.staticColumn.Check }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
 
</body>

</html>
```